# Degree of the field extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Could you help me showing that for a field $F$ the degree of the extension $F(x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}})\subset F(x)$ is $4$?

I have found the polynomial $y^{4}-(x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}})y^{2}+1$ such that $x$ is its root, but how can I prove that it is the minimal one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that $F(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})\subset F(x^2)\subset F(x)$. Now prove that each extension is of degree two.

Comment: I have tried that way either but I had a problem with the formal proof that $x^{2}\notin F(x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}})$.

Comment: For that proof $F(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})$ is invariant under the last two automorphisms on my list but $x^2$ is not.

Answer (score 3):

The solution by Brett is great. I just what to add that you can explicitly write the four automorphisms:

$$x\mapsto x$$
$$x\mapsto -x$$
$$x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$$
$$x\mapsto -\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: This works well ... unless $F$ happens to have characteristic two. In that case the extension isn't Galois (it's no longer separable), so it is pointless to look for more than two automorphisms.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen maybe you would care to add an answer for the characteristic 2 case ?

Comment: In characteristic two your third automorphism still tells that $F(x+1/x)$ is a proper subfield of $F(x)$. Then 
$$x^2+\frac1{x^2}=(x+\frac1x)^2,$$ so $F(x+1/x)$ is a purely inseparable extension of $F(x^2+1/x^2)$.